# Perform arithmetic on number array without iterating

Tags: java, arrays, math

For example, I would like to do something like the following in java:

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] result = numbers*2;
//result now equals {2,4,6,8,10};
```

Is this possible to do without iterating through the array? Would I need to use a different data type, such as ArrayList?  The current iterating step is taking up some time, and I'm hoping something like this would help.

Comment: Short answer: no you can't. If you could, the `*` operator would be implemented to run an iteration for you anyway.

Comment: How could any method be faster than O(n)? You have to multiply each entry...

Comment: Something like this may be possible in Haskell, with their fancy "lazy evaluation", but not in a language like Java.

Comment: So iterating the array and multiplying each element with 2 takes too much time? How long is your list? Furthermore, if there was another datatype it would just perform the iteration and multiplication internally... computations take time

Comment: If anything, maybe you could develop your own "lazy" evaluation, where  any modifications made to the whole array are only applied when the object is accessed.  Then, regardless of the size of the array, all mathematical operations would be O(1), with the reads taking longer.  Of course, this solution has its own set of complications, but it is something to consider if you are actually having trouble with large arrays.

Comment: You could use @kurtzbot 's idea, but keep in mind not all "constant" operations are created equal.

Comment: I'm doing more than just multiplying by 2, but that was a simple way of explaining it.  It appears the answer is no anyway, thanks @DougRamsey

Comment: @DavidK, I would have a look at my answer if you haven't already.  It may be over-engineering, but it will at least be fun to think about :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't multiply each item in an array without iterating through the entire array. As pointed out in the comments, even if you could use the `*` operator in such a way the implementation would still have to touch each item in the array.

Further, a different data type would have to do the same thing.

Comment: Just to add, this matter isn't bounded to Java. Any other language would have the same behavior in order to accomplish what OP ask.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza actually, no, there are functional languages with lazy evaluation where each element on the multiplied list wouldn't be created until some other expression actually required it.

Comment: @Alnitak even with lazy evaluation, if you must iterate the array after the operation, then every element will be multiplied lazily, it doesn't escape the O(n) time.

Answer (score 2):

I think a different answer from the obvious may be beneficial to others who have the same problem and don't mind a layer of complexity (or two).

In Haskell, there is something known as "Lazy Evaluation", where you could do something like multiply an infinitely large array by two, and Haskell would "do" that.  When you accessed the array, it would try to evaluate everything as needed.  In Java, we have no such luxury, but we can emulate this behavior in a controllable manner.

You will need to create or extend your own `List` class and add some new functions.  You would need functions for each mathematical operation you wanted to support. I have examples below.

```
LazyList ll = new LazyList();
// Add a couple million objects
ll.multiplyList(2);
```

The internal implementation of this would be to create a Queue that stores all the primitive operations you need to perform, so that order of operations is preserved. Now, each time an element is read, you perform all operations in the Queue before returning the result.  This means that reads are very slow (depending on the number of operations performed), but we at least get the desired result.

If you find yourself iterating through the whole array each time, it may be useful to de-queue at the end instead of preserving the original values.

If you find that you are making random accesses, I would preserve the original values and returned modified results when called.

If you need to update entries, you will need to decide what that means.  Are you replacing a value there, or are you replacing a value after the operations were performed? Depending on your answer, you may need to run backwards through the queue to get a "pre-operations" value to replace an older value.  The reasoning is that on the next read of that same object, the operations would be applied again and then the value would be restored to what you intended to replace in the list.

There may be other nuances with this solution, and again the way you implement it would be entirely different depending on your needs and how you access this (sequentially or randomly), but it should be a good start.

Comment: Yes, this is a bit of over-engineering for my application, but definitely could be applied to more complicated situations.

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction of Java 8 this task can be done using streams.

```
 private long tileSize(int[] sizes) {
    return IntStream.of(sizes).reduce(1, (x, y) -> x * y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. If your collection is really big and you want to do it faster you can try to operates on elements in 2 or more threads, but you have to take care of synchronization(use synchronized collection) or divide your collection to 2(or more) collections and in each thread operate on one collection. I'm not sure wheather it will be faster than just iterating through the array - it depends on size of your collection and on what you want to do with each element. If you want to use this solution you will have wheather is it faster in your case - it might be slower and definitely it will be much more complicated.
Generally - if it's not critical part of code and time of execution isn't too long i would leave it as it is now.